# Resolve Ambiguity window after set next statement in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When setting next statement in debug mode to a different line of code I'm getting this `Resolve Ambiguity` window:

[image]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/resolve-ambiguity-dialog-box?view=vs-2017):

> The Resolve Ambiguity dialog box appears when the debugger cannot
>   choose the location to display

What should I do in order to prevent this?

IIS version 7.5.76.

Comment: interested in how to recreate this. Can you post an example?

Comment: @kennyzx sorry but I don't know how to recreate it, it is not always happening.

Comment: Have you read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/resolve-ambiguity-dialog-box?view=vs-2017

Comment: *"The Resolve Ambiguity dialog box appears when the debugger **cannot choose the location to display**. ... ...the debugger has **multiple options**."*. Are you by any chance using async functions or Task or multiple HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (Thanks to @Liam suggestion):

It was a matter of multiple http requests to my server.